# What type of diode is this? Code T3G4E (or B), in glass housing (SOD64)

Tags: diodes, identification

[image]Trying to reverse engineer an "igniter" from an old Kubota 7 hp gasoline engine. Removed all the epoxy and now identifying parts. The 2 diodes are in parallel over the collector (cathode) and emitter (anode) of a Darlington transistor. Diode is yellow/greenish. Print on one of the diodes is quite good. T3G4E. I tried TB and T8. G48 and G4B too. No hits on datasheets.

[image]

Comment: Philips used to make a lot of these ceramic bead diodes. Not saying that your's is a Philips, but that seems like a likely manufacturer and might help you narrow it down.

Comment: It looks like an avalanche diode similar to this type: https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/VISH/VISHS84843/VISHS84843-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0 <-- if it is SOD-64 then it will have a 4.3 mm diameter (not to be confused with an SOD-57 with 3.6 mm diameter).

Comment: just measured the diameter. it's a 4.3mm.

Comment: I suspect the "T" is toshiba.