# What type of diodes are used in this setup (igniter from kubota gasoline engine)

Tags: diodes, identification

The 2 diodes in the picture are over the collector and emitter of a darlington transistor. In an earlier question here i was not able to find what type they were by their print (T3G4E). So maybe this schematic can help. The igniter setup is used in a 12v battery system.

There is also another part which needs identifying, which is the "C". I am not sure if it is a blown out protector or a condensator. It measures 2kOhm constant and my fluke goes out of range on the capacitance. This part was protected by shrink-tube, which I removed and found shell-parts. It could be that it was dissolved as i kept the board a long time in an acetone solution (to remove the epoxy)
This igniter is used in an old kubota gasoline 7hp engine and replaces the old contact points in the ignition system. the rotating armature has an extra "flag" which activates the igniter to create a spark. Are these diodes avalanche types?
[image]

Comment: There must be more to the circuit.  The Darlington isn't connected in a meaningful way currently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What type of diode is this? Code T3G4E (or B), in glass housing (SOD64)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/654135/what-type-of-diode-is-this-code-t3g4e-or-b-in-glass-housing-sod64)

Comment: I will double check again

Comment: I will double check again: done: The drawing is correct.  I used a strong magnifying glass and a multimeter to check. As a note: the power is made in the ignition coil which is mounted inside of the rotating armature. I assume the thyristor is the replacement of the "contact-points". so that leaves the darlington, maybe as a dampening? absorbing energy during constant rotation when the "flag" is not triggered. The darlington was also hooked up to the outer casing (collector) for cooling purpose but the whole igniter was mounted on plastic rings, so electrically isolated.